# Troubleshooting A Sump Pump (Zoeller)

Tags: electrical, plumbing, repair, switch

I have an older Zoeller sump pump that has stopped working. I found the pump submerged in the basin with a foot of water. I toggled the float before pulling it but it didn't kick on. Since removing it, I found a few articles online describing general troubleshooting steps, but not really helpful for a novice such as myself. What I am trying to determine is whether or not the motor is salvageable, buy replacing the switch, or if the sump pump is garbage. It's a very nice pump, from the previous owners of our home, and I'd like to try repairing it if possible. I removed the switch cover and tested the motor leads with my ohmmeter. There is continuity in the motor, however, I'm not sure how helpful this is in determining if it will work once the switch is replaced.

One article recommended bypassing the switch and then plugging the pump in, but I was wondering if someone else might have some advice.

Thanks for any help.

-Update-
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the sump pump's motor nameplate?

Comment: 53-D     O896 60H    ------    Is 0896, the MMYY?

Comment: We need an actual photo -- there are *lots* of specs on the nameplate

Comment: I found this from amazon, see last page: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/812qBvFlnUL.pdf

Comment: Does it work when the switch is bypassed?  (Stick it in a bucket o' water to test it BTW -- trying to pump air will cause it to overheat.)

Comment: You have an Ohmmeter, why not just continuity test the switch. Then you know if the switch is working.